# Does Allah dislike war?

Tags: quran, hadith, allah

I've tried to google and can't find the answers in Qu'ran and Hadith. Here's my question, does Allah dislike war? For example, war world II, etc.

Comment: Allah dislikes injustice, but war can be good or bad depending on the war

Answer (score -3):

First and firemost, we need to understand the cause and purpose of war..if it's against injustice and saving victim then its applicable. Quran says

"Permission to fight is given to those against whom war is made, because they have been wronged — and Allah indeed has power to help them" (Quran 22 :40)

And once peace prevail then war should be stopped immediately. If we study the islamic history then we will realise all the war took place in self defence. But if the intention is to harm people or humanity by war then its prohibited and would be considered as great Sin.“The Holy Quran clearly says that ” If you have killed even a single person, you have killed the whole humanity”. (Quran Surah maida)

By the above verse The Quran is actually promoting humanity and showing how important a human life is. It’s greater than Worship to save human life. There are rules of war set by Prophet Muhammad as follows:

Islamic Rules of War Given by Prophet Muhammad (PBUH)

Here is a glimpse of some of the Islamic rules of war based on the Hadith of Prophet Muhammad (PBUH):

1. No killing of children and women
2. No killing of elderly and sick persons
3. Exercising patience even during war
4. Not to head into war “hoping” for a conflict
5. Leaving the monks and those in places of worship alone
6. No destruction of property, cultivated lands and crops, etc.
7. No uprooting or burning of green and fruit-bearing trees
8. No slaughtering of animals for reasons other than food
9. No hurting or burning beesNo theft or robbery in the guise of war
10. Avoiding destruction to an inhabited place!

Hope it helps you.